# Round off in listview

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to round off each row to the nearest 1.0 in a column of a listview, so meaning  1.58 should show 2.00 and 1.48 should be 1.00 -

```
Math.Round(listView1.Columns[2].ToString(), 10);
```

Comment: Your question is no way related to `listview`, removed the tag. and What's your question?

Comment: What am I doing wrong in the code... this does not work, I tried looping and still nothing.

Comment: You should edit your values before you put them in the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't round a string directly.

```
string val=listView1.Columns[2].ToString(); 

double i; 
if(Double.TryParse(val, out i)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(i)); // you can use Math.Round without second
                                      // argument if you need rounding to the 
                                      // nearest unit  
}
```

Comment: @user3012159 so what I've written applies to you. You need to Parse the string to a double before rounding it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `0` in digits parameter. You expect no digits here, but you're passing `10` to digit parameter which says to round with 10 digits after decimal.

```
var res =  Math.Round(1.58, 0);//2
var res =  Math.Round(1.48, 0);//1
```

Just saw you try to `Round` the string, You'll have to convert it to `Double` or `decimal` or whatever.

```
var rounded = Math.Round(Double.Parse(listView1.Columns[2].ToString()), 0);
```

Comment: I dont know what the number will be as this pulls from a db, all I know this needs to be rounded off to the nearest.

Comment: That means your `listView1.Columns[2].ToString()` doesn't have a valid number. Is that contains alphabets?

Comment: What was the data in that column? Edit your question with the value of `listView1.Columns[2].ToString()`

Comment: The values in the column are all different in each row... this listview is reading from a db. the column 2 is Price

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to get *String* as a final result (as far as you've put *ToString()* in your code), you may just use appropriate *formatting string* ("F0" in your case):

```
  String result = (1.58).ToString("F0"); // <- "2"
  ...
  String result = (1.48).ToString("F0"); // <- "1"
```